# Does web audio API support controlling the volume of each of stereo channels, left and right?

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

I'm going to develop a JavaScript game which depends mainly on audio effects.

I made some searches on whether **Web Audio API** supports controlling the volume of both of stereo channels, left and right so that I can volume Up/Down one of them? I did not find any answers for my inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want a stereo panner node. That would be the simplest way to control volume in the left/right channels.

If for some reason you want more control over the individual channels, you can use a splitter node to turn the stereo signal into two mono signals, modify the mono signals individually, and then use a channel merger node to turn them back into a stereo signal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! :)

Is there a tutorial for this technique ? I searched every where but did not find any tutorials for this API.

Comment: I haven't done this myself, so I don't know exactly every method you call, but if you look up the documentation on the nodes I mentioned (stereoPanner, splitter, merger) that should point you in the right direction.